# How to delete a module in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, ide

Is there a way to delete a module within Android Studio?
When I right click on a module I can't find an option for deletion, is it elsewhere?

Comment: I can't believe Android Studio makes such common operation so un-intuitive.

Answer (score 665, accepted):

The "Mark as Excluded" option isn't there anymore.

The current (Android Studio **0.8.x - 2.2.x**) way to do this is via the **Project Structure** dialog. It can be accessed via "File -> Project Structure" or by right-clicking on a Module and selecting "Module Settings".

[image]

Then select the module, and click the "minus" button to remove it.

[image]

The directory will still be visible in the "Project" view (though not in the "Android" view) since it's not actually deleted, but it will no longer be treated as a module.

If you want, you can then physically delete the files it by right-clicking on it and pressing "Delete".

Comment: Why the android studio is so critical and confusing

Comment: And than ... ? files are still cached and possibly referenced (modules.xml, ...). Is it safe to remove the whole module directory from disk?

Comment: @Wooff Yes, you can then delete it safely.

Comment: If you wanted to delete entire project would you still need to remove app from project structure first? Would just deleting the project's folder cleanly remove it?

Comment: @michael I'm not sure I understand the question... if you're going to discard the full project then there's no point in removing the modules from it first.

Comment: ok, that's what i wanted to check. several tutorials, like this one on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvFCRl_zxsw, instruct to remove app and activity modules first before deleting project folder for a clean project delete.

Comment: @matiash, I am removing the module as you described but it gets automatically re-added.
**Edit**: removed from gradle as G_V suggested below, now it is fine.

Comment: I'm using Android 1.3.2 and this methods works, too!

Comment: What a big c**p they put in the world with Android Studio!

Comment: I think Android framework and Android Studio have this thing for extra complicating simple things. Only now Google has got into senses and it is becoming developer friendly day by day.

Comment: If you remove the module like this, it won't be reflected in the VCS. So the way I do it is to manually delete the directory, remove it from `settings.gradle` and remove any implementations from other modules.

Answer (score 98):

*(Editor's Note: This answer was correct in May 2013 for Android Studio v0.1, but is no longer accurate as of July 2014, since the mentioned menu option does not exist anymore -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24592192/82788) for up-to-date alternative).*

First you will have to mark it as excluded. 
Then on right click you will be able to delete the project.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

Comment: After doing the steps in this answer, the project remains in the list, and I have to restart Android Studio to make the project disappear from the list. For whoever experiencing the same thing, please restart Android Studio. :)

Comment: You can just refresh to achieve same

Comment: I'm sure this 'was' a great answer, but it is out of date. The one referencing Android Studio 0.8.1 worked for me.

Answer (score 66):

In Android Studio **1.0 - 1.1b4**, I found this to be the easiest way to remove a module:

1. *Open `settings.gradle` found under Gradle Scripts*
2. *Delete module's name from the include statement*
3. *Sync Project with Gradle Files*
4. *Optionally, delete it manually from the project folder*

Example

**Old:**

```
include ':app', ':greendao'
```

**New:**

```
include ':app'
```

Comment: This is the true way to get ghost modules from popping back up.

Answer (score 18):

As I saw that in Android Studio 0.5.1, you have to close your project by doing simply File -> Close Project then move your mouse over the project which you want to delete then keep your mouse on the same project and press delete then click on "OK" button that would delete your project from Android Studio.

[image: screenshot 1]

[image]

Comment: You are just removing the project from the Recent Projects list. The project's content will still be available on disk.

Comment: hmm Afaik that is not possible to delete from disk in Android Studio as ADT does

Comment: I concur, and that's a bummer.

Comment: This answer is about deleting a project, but the question was about deleting a module.

Answer (score 9):

In Android studio v1.0.2

*Method 1*

Go to project structure, `File -> Project Structure...`, as the following picture show, click `-` icon to remove the module.[image]

*Method 2*

Edit the file `settings.gradle` and remove the entry you are going to delete. e.g. edit the file from `include ':app', ':apple'` to `include ':app'`.

That will work in most of the situation, however finally you have to delete the module from disk manually if you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to delete manually (for me it was easier), follow this:

Let's get this example with "teste".

**1 -  First change the explorer to "project" and open "settings.gradle";**

[image]

**2 - Delete the module you want;**

[image]

**3 - Go to your root folder of your project and delete the module folder.**

[image]

Comment: This is still the best method. No Issue has occurred.

Answer (score 8):

Here is for `Android studio 2.3.3`
I did not find any Project Structure under `File` menu. 
So here are steps in pictures

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Step-1:** Right Click on Project-->Open Module Option
[image: Right Click on Project and Select modules]

**Step-2:**
Click Your Module --> click (-)sign done on Top Left in PopUp, then press ok button.
[image: Select Module want to delete]

**Step-3:** After removing module from the project
[image: After removing module from the project]

**Step-4:** Again do right-click in Project, Select Delete menu to Remove whole content from Disk space(i.e.folder).
[image]

**Step-5:** Delete the content of the module from the disk by clicking done.
[image: Delete the content of the module from the disk by clicking done]

Answer (score 4):

Deleting is such a headache. I am posting the solution for Android Studio 1.0.2.

Step 1: Right click on the "Project Name" selected from the folder hierarchy like shown. 
Note: It can also be deleted from the Commander View from right hand side of your window by right clicking the project name and selecting delete from the context menu.

[image: Step 1]

Step 2: The project is deleted(seemingly) but gradle seems to keep the record of the project app folder(Check it by clcking on the Gradle View). Now go to **File->Close Project.**

Step 3: Now you are at the start window. Move the cursor on the  in recent project list. Press **Delete**.

Step 4: Delete the folder from the explorer by moving or deleting it actually. This location is in **your_user_name->Android Studio Projects->...**

Step 5: Go back to the Android studio window and the project is gone for good. You can start a new project now.

Answer (score 4):

1. edit the project's **settings.gradle** file: delete the module name (**, ':xxxxx'**) where **xxxxx** is the module name to be deleted
2. using the file explorer delete the module folder

by the way, the current version of the Android Studio (v3.1.2) throws an exception and exits the removing with an error while I'm removing the module through **Module Settings => selected module => - (minus)**

Best Regards, thanks)

Answer (score 4):

Steps to follow Remove Modules in Android Studio:3.1.4.

1. Goto Project-->Right Click on Module *(FolderIcon-GreywithGreenColorDot)*
   -->Load/UnLoadModules in PopUp
   -->Select Which Module to Unload in PopUpWindow[image: Refer this Image]
2. Again RightClick on Module *(FolderIcon-OrangeColor)* -->Remove module.
3. Finally, RightClick again on Module *(FolderIcon-GreyColor)* -->Delete.

   Note:Incase Project Enabled with Git please remove module from *settings.gradle*, otherwise deleted module.iml will show in project module list([Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532881/can-you-regenerate-a-deleted-modules-iml-file-in-android-studio)).gradle.xml which is located in project/.idea/gradle.xml--remove a module from here.

Hope it helps.
Thank-you.

Answer (score 4):

**Android Studio delete a module**

`settings.gradle`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58061491/4770877) file is responsible for modules in the project

1. Remove <module_name> from `settings.gradle`. Also it can contains `projectDir`  setting
2. remove module from <module_name> `build.gradle`

```
implementation project(':<module_name>')
```

3. `Sync Project with Gradle Files`

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently running the 0.5.8 version of Android Studio and I can't even find the "Mark folder as" option when I right click, what I do is:

Right click on project -> Click on Show in Explorer and then just delete it from there.

You can achieve the same result by deleting it directly through Windows Explorer. That's the only way I've been able to get rid of Projects I did not want anymore. Oh and of course, this also removes it from the hard disk.

Answer (score 3):

For the latest Android Studio Versions, to delete a module in Android Studio :

```
1. Open File -> Project Structure
2. Choose the Modules section from the left column.
3. In the right panel opened ,select the module you want to delete.
4. After selecting the module tap the (-) icon on the top to delete the respective module.
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the following:

- You are working with Android Studio 1.2.1 or 1.2.2 (I don't have the latest yet, will edit this again when I do).
- Your Project Tool Window is displaying one of the following views: "Project", "Packages", "Android" or "Project Files"

You can delete an Android Studio module as follows:

1. In the Project Tool Window click the module you want to delete.
2. Between the Tool Bar and the Project Tool Window the tool bar you will see two "chips" that represent the path to the selected module, similar to:    **your-project-name > selected-module-name**
3. Right click on the *selected-module-name* chip.  A context menu with multiple sections will appear.  In the third section from the bottom there will be a section that contains "Reformat Code..", "Optimize Imports..." and "Delete".
4. Select "Delete" and follow any prompts.

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable way I have found to do this it to go to project structure and remove it from dependencies and remove it from your setting.gradle file.

It will appear as if it is fully deleted at his point but it is not. If you try to re add the module it will say that it already exist in the project.

The final step is to go to the location of your project using file explorer etc and delete the module.

This work 100% of the time on studio 1.3.1

Answer (score 2):

In android-studio version 2. just go

Right Click on `Project`-->Open `Module Option`-->Click `Your Module` --> click `sign done` then press `ok` button.

Answer (score 0):

After doing what's referred in [this answer]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24592192/82788

Select the module(since it's still visible on the Project view),pressing Delete button on the keyboard can delete this module on disk.(Before doing what's referred in that answer, the Delete button has no effect.)

Answer (score 0):

Remove from File > File Structure > Dependencies > - button. Then if it is stull there you can remove the module by going to the settings.gradle file and removing it from the include line.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a module in `Android Studio 2.3.3`,

- Open `File -> Project Structure`
- On `Project Structure` window, list of modules of the current project gets displayed on left panel. Select the module which needs to be deleted.
- Then click `-` button on top left, that means just above left panel.