# Remove Project from Android Studio

Tags: android, import, export, android-studio

Does any one know how to remove a project from Android Studio in an attempt to re- export it from Eclipse?

So far I have tried removing all the gradle files associated with the project, which causes an error when Android Studio tries to open my project.

These files were not located in AndriodStudioProjects Folder because I only imported the project it was not moved....

Basically what I would like to accomplish is, removing the file from the list of recent projects in Android Studio, re-export it from Eclipse and then import a working project back into Android Studio.

Comment: why is android studio so convoluted and difficult to use?

Comment: @AKh Probably cause its still in beta v 0.8.0 . I dig the dark theme though wish there was a better solution than moonrise in eclipse. but eclipse has become so mature. Probably jetbrains is too busy supporting intelliJ, that android studio is just not as high priority right now. Hopefully a full v1 comes out soon though.

Comment: Thank you :).. Hopefully V1.0 will be better. I am a long time eclipse user... Not sure if it is the transition that is making studio very difficult to use or in general studio is not up to the standard...

Comment: Personally I think Android Studio is way easier to use than eclipse but this is as of 2016 of course

Comment: @inner_class7 - Currently AndroidStudio is 2.3.2 and long out of beta.  Yet it still has this foible.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

File > Close Project

move your mouse cursor on the project and press Delete keyboard button :)

EDIT
try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710290/how-to-delete-a-project-in-android-studio), works for me

Comment: not working. . . I closed the project and the project highlights blue and i click command + delete(mac) and nothing happens

Comment: see my answer, i tried your way and it wasn't working again I am on a mac so maybe im doing something wrong but it didn't delete.

Comment: This threw me off on a mac too... first, you can't click on the project to select it or it launches the project... you have to trick it by moving your mouse over to highlight and then to make sure it sticks use the keyboard arrow keys up/down to highlight the one you want. Then fn+delete to remove it because mac keyboards are retarded.

Comment: This just removes it from "Recently opened projects" on Linux

Comment: Yep. If you want to delete its files just delete it files from window explorer

Comment: Delete button on project in Project Window doesn't work. Delete can be found in project context menu in breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 41):

This is for Android Studio 1.0.2(Windows7). Right click on the project on project bar and delete.

[image: delete from studio]

Then remove the project folder from within your user folder under 'AndroidStudioProject' using Windows explorer.

Close the studio and relaunch you will presented with welcome screen. Click on deleted project from left side pane then select the option to remove from the list. Done!

[image: remove from list]

Comment: No "Delete" option is available in that menu (on Linux)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul .. see the first line of my answer which states "Windows7".

Answer (score 20):

In the "Welcome to Android Studio" opening dialog you can highlight the app you want to remove from Android Studio and hit delete on your keyboard.

Comment: This helped me remove the unwanted projects from the list, +1. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You must close the project, hover over the project in the welcome screen, then press the delete button.

Answer (score 7):

1. Go to your Android project directory

   ```
   C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects
   ```

   [image: Screenshot]
2. Delete which one you need to delete
3. Restart Android Studio

Answer (score 6):

Found this elsewhere on the web, it deletes basically everything (except the workspace.xml file, which you can delete manually from the project folder).

1. Right Click on the project name under the save icon.
2. Click delete
3. Go to your project folder and check all the files were deleted.

[image]

Comment: There is no Delete item in Android Studio Bumblebee.

Answer (score 5):

The project can be removed from the "recent project" list but it will still remain in the project directory.
To remove from the project list:

1. Close the project
2. Highlight the project in the "recent project" list
3. Press Backspace (NOT Delete!)

To completely remove the project:

1. List item
2. Use Windows File Explorer to navigate to the Android Studio project directory (normally in "x:\Users\YourName\AndroidStudioProjects")
3. Select the project to delete
4. Press Delete (NOT Backspace!)

Comment: Here's how you find the project directory path under Linux: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17947360/2535335

Answer (score 3):

MAKE IT SIMPLE

1. Open Project
2. Go to AndroidStudioProjects Folder
3. Right click on the project name to delete
4. click Delete

[image: Delete Android Studio Project]

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is close the project. Using file explorer head to the location of that project and delete.

Alot of processes, even simply deleting can be annoying to figure out in studio. Most deleting options a good work around is to delete using file explorer. This is a part of the process tht works for deleting modules as well. Which u will prob find is painful as well

Answer (score 1):

Select your project in the projects window > File > Project Structure > (in the Modules section) select your project and click the minus button.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you don't want to build it just remove it from `settings.gradle` file

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove my project from eclipse entirely. To do so I copied the folder of my project in workspace and pasted it onto my desktop. Then navigated back into eclipse right clicked selected delete and then check the box to delete the project from my workspace.

After this I closed eclipse. Opened Android studio and tried to open my imported project. At this point it told me the project didn't exist and provided me with an option to remove it from the list. After clicking this i closed Android Studio, and when i reopened it the project was gone.

Finally, I reopened eclipse and imported my project from existing sources to get it back inside eclipse.

**NOTE**

I would advise against using Android Studio on projects that you have that already work fine with eclipse. Android studio is cool when you are creating new projects but from my experience there are a lot of problems with build paths when I import a build.gradle from  eclipse to Android Studio. Android Studio is great but remember it is still in the I/O pre-release!!!

--Just my 2 cents!

Comment: I wish it was more stable. It's a great tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to delete/cut as suggested by @Pacific P. Regmi and if you are getting "Folder in use" which won't let you to delete/cut make sure to close all the android studio instances.

Answer (score 0):

The location of `SDK` is incorrect, the name of one filer is with place this is creating an issue. By removing that space issue will be resolved.
old `SDK` location:

```
C:\Users\At Tech\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

new `SDK` location:

```
F:\AndroidSDK\Sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's Windows, all you need to do is delete the root of that project within the file explorer. Just right click on the name of the app in Android Studio, and then "show in file explorer". Then just delete the project folder all in all.