# Android Studio: Default project directory

Tags: android, path, project, android-studio

Whenever I create a new project in `Android Studio` it wants to put it in a generic default folder at a location something similar to (dependent on OS - Ubuntu here):

```
/home/USER/AndroidStudioProjects/
```

I want to change this directory to another location. Besides selecting this new location on the creation of every project, is there a setting (couldn't find) or `path variable` (couldn't find any documentation) that can set this directory (say `/home/USER/Projects/AndroidStudio/`) as the default?

Something similar to changing the workspace in Eclipse is what I am looking for.

Comment: Related post - [Change default save location of projects (or Workspace ) in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18012638/465053)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

At some point I too tried to do this, but the Android Studio doesn’t work quite like Eclipse does.

It's simpler: if you create a project at, say `/home/USER/Projects/AndroidStudio/MyApplication` from there on all new projects will default to `/home/USER/Projects/AndroidStudio`.

You can also edit `~/.AndroidStudioPreview/config/options/ide.general.xml` (in linux) and change the line that reads `<option name="lastProjectLocation" value="$USER_HOME$/AndroidStudioProjects" />` to `<option name="lastProjectLocation" value="$USER_HOME$/Projects/AndroidStudio" />`, but be aware that as soon as you create a project anywhere else this will change to that place and all new projects will default to it.

Hope this helps, but the truth is there really isn't much more to it other than what I explained here.

Answer (score 37):

This may be what you want.
[Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings > Project Opening > Default Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcVOo.png)

1. Open 'Preferences'
2. Select System Settings -> Project Opening
3. Set 'Default Directory' where you want.

It worked for me. I tried Android Studio 3.5.

Comment: Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Project Opening -> Default Directory
This is the simplest solution with the newer android studio 3.5^

Comment: Absolutely the answer I've been looking for. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 12):

In android studio 2.3.3 (windows) you must go to **C:\User\ (Name)\ .AndroidStudio2.3\config\option**  open **recentProjects.xml** 
And change your directory

**`<option name="lastProjectLocation" value="YOUR DIRECTORY" />`**

Comment: I believe the "option" in your path (...config\option...) should be "options". Also I have a recentProjects.xml but not a recentProject.xml .

Answer (score 11):

I found an easy way:

1. Open a new project;
2. Change the project location name by typing and not the **Browse...** button;
3. The **Next** button will appear now.

Comment: sorry, but I've tried that before, and tried it again just now. Doesn't work. On Windows 7 it defaults back to the old directory, which is just crazy. One would think that something so many people would like to change can be added to the IDE.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Answer (score 3):

- This worked for me :-
  -> Go to settings
  -> Type system setting in search bar
  -> Select your location
  -> Press Apply

Answer (score 2):

Top of The Android Studio Title bar its shows the complete file path or Location

[image: Look this image]

Answer (score 1):

File -> Other Settings -> Default settings... -> Terminal --> Project setting --> Start Directory --> ("Browse or Set Your Project Directory Path")

Now Close current Project and Start New Project Then Let Your eyes see Project Location

Comment: Please explain your answer!

Comment: well, it's not working when trying to open an existing project from the android studio start page ( http://prntscr.com/nj1xe4 ) but upvoted because it's working when try to open a new project or create a new project.

Answer (score 0):

I have Android Studio version 3.1.2, it shows project full path when you click **Build** tab in bottom-left location of the studio.

[image]

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: People googled "Android Studio: Default project directory" and found this answer. That's how it answers the question.

Comment: The question is asking "How to **change** the default path of project?" your answer says how to see path to "current project". if you are posting an answer, you need to try and answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`File\Other Settings\Preferences` for `New Projects\Teminal\Start Directory`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me Android Studio 4.0.1:

1. Close Android Studio.
2. Navigate to C:\Users[Username].AndroidStudio4.0\config\options
3. Locate recentProjects.xml and open it.
4. Scroll down the page you will notice: `<option name="lastProjectLocation" value="$USER_HOME$/AndroidStudioProjects" />`
5. Change $USER_HOME$/AndroidStudioProjects to your desired location: /home/USER/AndroidStudioProjects/
6. Reopen Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Android Studio 4.1.3 is currently located: **C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects**