# Change default save location of projects (or Workspace ) in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How to Change default save location of projects in Android Studio? Is there anything like workspaces in Android Studio too

Comment: Related post - [Android Studio: Default project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17800615/465053)

Answer (score 7):

> It's simpler: if you create a project at, say /home/USER/Projects/AndroidStudio/MyApplication from there on all new projects will default to /home/USER/Projects/AndroidStudio.

[Android Studio: Default project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800615/android-studio-default-project-directory)

Answer (score 5):

In Intellij/Android Studio, the project itself stores the directory of it's own location. In Eclipse, the IDE itself stores the directory of the projects.

Here's some comparisons between Android Studio and Eclipse:

1) Workspace

Android Studio= C:\Users\582767\AndroidStudioProjects

Eclipse= C:\Users\582767\workspace

2) Package Explorer

Android Studio= Doesn't have one

Eclipse= Has it in the IDE

[image]

3) Android Application

Android Studio=

[image]

Eclipse= In Eclipse, the Android App is shown alongside all your other apps. Android Studio doesn't do that.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Create new project -> Select Project Location
```

Care to be taken that there should not be any blank space in Project Location Path.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

Import any the project from your desired location. That desired location will be set your workspace