# How to switch Workspace in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Can't find the option in Android Studio to switch between workspaces like in Eclipse.
Is there only way to add path when creating Project? Or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before start exploring Android Studio please read **[Project and File Structure](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/studio/index.html#project-structure)**

You can try with -> Press `Cntrl+Shift+F` Then change **Directory** Location .

> [Change default save location of projects (or Workspace ) in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012638/change-default-save-location-of-projects-or-workspace-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 4):

you can open a separate window that how it goes in android studio since this is based on IntelliJ IDE, 
click on
**File-->open-->open and select the project**, this will ask you in a window saying do you want to open in new window or same click on new window.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this steps given below, because the Android Studio doesn’t work quite like Eclipse does. It's simpler: if you create a project at, say /home/USER/Projects/AndroidStudio/MyApplication from there on all new projects will default to /home/USER/Projects/AndroidStudio. So, your current directory will be your current workspace.

1- Open new project

2- Change project location name by typing and not browse button

3- Next button will appear now

And if you want to change current then rename current directory and reopen that project.