# How can I change default home directory for Android studio

Tags: android-studio

My workspace for android studio project is in C:\AndroidStudioProjects. 
I try this
[Android Studio: Default project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800615/android-studio-default-project-directory)
but it's not working... plz help me to quickly access projects

[image: Android Studio 2.1 Open File or Project Dialog]

As shown in the screenshot, there must be some configuration file to change that.

Looking for some hack. So that when I click the home button and it opens my specified directory.
for windows platform.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800615/android-studio-default-project-directory?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Many default settings in Android Studio are insanely frustrating without any solution :(. The recent project button (below `Hide path` link) on the very right seems to be the only hope in this case which is bit helpful.

Comment: Related post - [Change default save location of projects (or Workspace ) in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18012638/465053)

Answer (score 0):

Create a project and save like that address:
`/home/USER/Projects/AndroidStudio/MyApplication`

So, the new future projects will be:
`/home/USER/Projects/AndroidStudio`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me Android Studio 4.0.1:

1. Close Android Studio.
2. Navigate to C:\Users[Username].AndroidStudio4.0\config\options
3. Locate recentProjects.xml and open it.
4. Scroll down the page you will notice: `<option name="lastProjectLocation" value="$USER_HOME$/AndroidStudioProjects" />`
5. Change $USER_HOME$/AndroidStudioProjects to your desired location lets say desktop: `$USER_HOME$/Desktop/`
6. Reopen Android studio.

Answer (score -2):

Android studio does not allow you to set the home directory. It is better to use recent project.