# Change location for Android Studio home dir on Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

I changed the android studio workspace, .gradle location and all other paths to point to /local/mnt/workspace but I am not able to change the location for Android Studio home directory on Ubuntu and it still points to /usr2/ . How  do I change setting so that .AndroidStudio folder (for example: .AndroidStudioPreview2.0) gets created under /local/mnt/workspace rather than /usr2/ directory.

Comment: did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path) ?

Comment: might help with your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800615/android-studio-default-project-directory

Comment: @Blackbelt : I changed the sdk location already, that does not change the Android Studio directory.

Comment: @geek90 : That is just to change the workspace, does not change the Home dir.

Comment: Check https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827407-Changing-IDE-default-directories-used-for-config-plugins-and-caches-storage

Comment: Thanks. This is much better. I changed:
idea.config.path
idea.system.path
idea.plugins.path
idea.log.path

and now most of the files got updated to desired folder. Even ./AndroidStudioPreview2.0 is still created and also has system folder under it but it's empty. It's Ok for me. Please submit answer and I will accept it.