# Android Studio Project Dependancy on Eclipse Project

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio

I have few model classes that I have to use on Client as well as Server side. I have created an Eclipse project (Server code) with all the Models. Now I wan't to use the same classes in my Android project. I want Android Studio to be depend on that project to use those classes. I don't want to copy the classes as they might change over the time and I will need to re-copy every time my model changes.

Or a config changes which would say "use these files from this location for this Android Studio Project" would also do.

Comment: Please [check these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800615/android-studio-default-project-directory.)

Comment: @AmitVaghela Thanks! But I think it doesn't answers my questions. I want to create android project in some different location but use few classes from all together different location.