# Move AndroidStudioProjects to other Disk

Tags: android-studio

My disk C has very little space because of the `SSD`, how can I move the `C:\Users\Edu\AndroidStudioProjects` to `disk D`? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just copy and paste `AndroidStudioProjects` on disk D, then instead of reopen the project from the recent list, browse to the new directory.

If you want to change the default directory where AS creates projects read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17947360/5251245)

P.S. the tag is wrong, you should use Android Studio, not Android

Comment: It is important to note that the new directory should better avoid spaces, too.

Comment: Thank very much! and sorry for the tag hehe.