# Flutter Default Project Location

Tags: flutter, dart

For all of my projects done on Flutter, they all are stored into one directory by default unless I manually change the project's storage location. Is there any way from which I can change the default directory where it stores in so that when I want to save / start a new project, it automatically is saved in that folder?
Thanks.

Comment: How do you create your projects?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line in the folder of your choice : `flutter create NameProject`

Answer (score 0):

this worked with me
Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings > Project Opening > Default Directory

you can find the answer here
[Android Studio: Default project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800615/android-studio-default-project-directory)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).