# How to delete a project in Android Studio 0.8.9?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073108/remove-project-from-android-studio) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710290/how-to-delete-a-module-in-android-studio) question. Answers are either outdated or not correct.

Comment: Are you trying to delete a module or the project? For a module the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/q/16710290/82788 should work. For deleting a whole project you can just remove it from disk.

Answer (score 3):

15 March 2015 - Close project in Android Studio, close Android Studio, delete project using the OS file manager (delete from disk) and reopen Android Studio. Worked for me Android Studio v1.1, MS Windows.

Comment: This is the right answer. The key is to close Android Studio before deleting the folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can always navigate to android studio workspace directory (where your projects are saved) and delete the folder yourself, the next time you open android studio that project will be deleted.

Comment: What about the grade files, and other dependencies? This is not the professional way though.

Comment: @Alam I know it's not a professional way, but it's working, what about dependencies? if you want to remove them too they are on different folders, otherwise they are not removed

Comment: I have read a comment in a question here in SO that the folder deletion method is breaking the Android Studio. I don't want to risk the installation at this time.

Comment: @Alam rly? I highly doubt that, as long as you are deleting ONLY the folder of the project you want, nothing should go wrong. I've done it million times (I even did it before posting this answer to make sure it works) and so far Android Studio has no problem running flawlessly. In the worst case scenario you could re-install android studio, assuming java is already installed it shouldn't be that a big problem although I understand it's an unnecessary hassle

Comment: You can then delete the project from the lists of recent projects by selecting it then pressing the delete key.  This behaviour is consistent with the IntelliJ Community Edition of their IDE.  I don't like it, so I use Eclipse for non-Android projects.

Comment: It's remarkable that the "great" Android Studio doesn't have a simple delete option... what else did the Google missed, since they missed a very basic thing.

Answer (score 1):

MAKE IT SIMPLE (Only 4 steps)

1. Open Project
2. Go to AndroidStudioProjects Folder
3. Right Click on the project name to delete
4. Click Delete

more [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073108/remove-project-from-android-studio/39955826#39955826)