# How to delete a project safely in android studio.?

Tags: android, android-studio, delete-file

I want to delete a project in android studio with all files should be removed from the directory also.

Am using android studio 2.1.2, upon right click on the project there is no delete option

I have already check in this link [Remove Project from Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073108/remove-project-from-android-studio)  there were some solution such as,

```
1.move your mouse cursor on the project and press Delete keyboard button
2.Go to your Android project directory
  Delete which one you need to delete
  Restart Android Studio
```

but i need a better solution to remove it permanently in the directory also with safe mode.

Which one is best solution stated above or is there any solution to do it.? would appreciated expected solution.thanks.!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073108/remove-project-from-android-studio

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvFCRl_zxsw

Answer (score 1):

You can simply delete it by following some simple steps:

1. Click on projects
2. Select project that need to be deleted
3. Right click on it
4. Goto Show in Explorer
5. A window opens that shows the project you need to be deleted
6. Delete it..

Answer (score 0):

second solution is for mac ok:

1.go to folder: "AndroidStudioProjects"

2.then delete project folder that you want

3.reopen the android studio.