# How to delete a project in Android studio

Tags: android

I am new to android studio. I imported the project files from another directory. But now I want to remove that project without deleting the source files.

On android studio it shows the recent files and settings icon but no option to delete.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Project from Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073108/remove-project-from-android-studio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the project. Right-click on the project name above android in the path.

[image]

Click delete. close the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this link  [here](https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts-v2/appendix/appendix-utilities/appendix-utilities.html#:%7E:text=label%3D%22%40string/app_name%22-,How%20to%20delete%20a%20project,the%20delete%20key%20or%20click%20the%20X%20that%27s%20displayed%20on%20it.,-How%20to%20extract)

It shows you how to delete a project in Android Studio and more.