# delete project in android Studio 0.3.4

Tags: android-studio

i have some old projects in my android studio ide.
I never need them.
When I right click on a project I can't find an option for deletion, is it elsewhere?

how i can delete a project in android studio 0.3.4  ?

Answer (score 11):

Open the .idea/modules.xml, and delete you module, then right click on you module, you can see Delete....

Comment: I had been looking for this all around, thank you! (Using AS 0.5.7)

Answer (score 0):

You have to mark the project folder as excluded, once you've done this, you'll see the 'delete' option.

This method is explained with more detail in this link, which seems to be the same you're looking for

[How to delete a module in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710290/how-to-delete-a-project-in-android-studio)