# Android studio, how to delete folder with references?

Tags: android, android-studio

i would like to delete one folder (unused library) from my project in Android Studio. But i cannot to do that by delete key on keyboard or any other way.

I tried to found delete under refactor->safe delete, but this option is disabled.

If i removed folder manually from folder, Android studio created a folder again and putted in one .iml file, so i cannot delete folder again.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 21):

1. Remove it from settings.gradle
2. Build --> Clean (the blue rectangle should disappear)
3. Right click on module -->Delete

Comment: that was so hard finally when you know where to look. A few ours later...

Answer (score 6):

To remove a module, you first have to delete it from `.idea/modules.xml`.

Once you do that and save the file, you'll be able to delete the folder, which will no longer be marked with the module's blue rectangle.

**Don't forget to remove the module from `settings.gradle`**.

I found this aswer at [delete project in android Studio 0.3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876758/delete-project-in-android-studio-0-3-4)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is occurring because of workspace.xml and modules.xml inside .idea directory of your project.

You cant not delete any module if there is blue rectangle over it, Follow the steps to delete your module from project :

1. Go to File> Project Structure , select the module you want to delete and press the red minus sign button to remove.

   **Note :** Also remove if any reference in build.gradle file of your main module.
2. Clean your project using Build > Clean Project
3. Close your Android Studio now
4. Go to the project directory and delete the your_project.iml file and content of .idea folder from project root directory, also delete  the module directory which you want to remove.
5. Open Android Studio again and let it sync the project with gradle
6. If module appears again there will not be any blue rectangle mark on it so you can delete by right click > delete and clean your project.
7. Sync your project again with gradle, if it appears again check your event log if somewhere something from library is used, if it is remove them all.Check your `File > Project` Structure as well if there are any error referring to your module library on bottom. If it is using the red bulb button remove it.
8. After remove all things Clean Your project and sync again.

Let me know in comments if any problem occurs.

Comment: sorry forgot to add clean option after delete. updated

Comment: There are some bugs which are making this harder than necessary; it will be better for 0.4.3 or maybe the version after that; track progress at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64720 and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61529

Comment: Under 0.5.3, remove the module from the project structure then you can go to the Project Window and delete the module.  No need to go outside Studio.

Comment: Somebody down-voted the answer, I just want to mention that the above answer was the only available option to delete a module that time. Android Studio is in developer preview release and changes are happening weekly. It would not be possible for me to edit all answers weekly so you are requested to do judgement accordingly.