# How to delete a project in Android Studio 0.3.6

Tags: android, android-studio

How do you delete a project in the Android Studio? This question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710290/how-to-delete-a-project-in-android-studio)
but that was in May, i am using the latest version and this step is not available.Any help?

Comment: In your folder that contains your project; Right-click, delete.

Comment: It worked.Strange way to do it though.

Comment: Sorry I meant to answer and not comment! But yeah it is strange. I wish AS had a easy way to delete it. But they don't expect you to be deleting very often. That is probably why.

Comment: But you said it yourself in the edit of that answer that "This answer was correct in May 2013 for Android Studio v0.1", do you notice the difference in version number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know to do it, albeit slightly unorthodox; in your folder that contains your project; select -right click - delete.