# Reusable code for both Mobile and Wear Modules in Android Studio

Tags: android, module, android-studio, code-reuse

What are best practices for creating reusable code for both the mobile and wear modules (or glass/tv/auto modules) in android studio? My reasons are to keep my application very thin, and prevent reuse of some session classes.

I was thinking about creating going `File -> New Module`?

Seems like an easy question to answer, can someone chip in?

Comment: Modules is the way to go. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592027/whats-the-best-practice-for-sharing-classes-between-a-wear-and-android-app/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you can create new Module and call it "Common" for example
Check this project https://github.com/tajchert/SWear_Weather

Comment: Shall we have the jniLibs directory in the common module?