# .iml file does not exist - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, bitbucket

I'm trying to clone a project from BitBucket to my Android Studio. Finally it ends up with the error .iml file does not exist. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Edit:- Once project is loaded from my repo, it says Error loading project. Two modules can not be loaded, those two modules are .iml files.

Comment: Please see this question,  it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/27532881/794088

Comment: I did not delete those files. They can not be loaded from my repository.

Comment: Well, I got it solved. After cloning the project, just reopen it. If you have cloned project to D:\Android folder, in Studio, File>Open and open that project, it works. have no idea why and how.

Comment: this answer helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/27532990/3583680

Comment: This solution worked for me . https://stackoverflow.com/a/54644331/5033303

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It happened to me when I open my app from Android Studio's "Open Recent" option after cloning from my repository.
Just close the app and re-open from "Open" option. It worked for me.

Answer (score 38):

I faced similar problem, It just solved for by following steps -
1. Close you IntelliJ
2. Go to your codebase directory 
3. delete the .idea folder
4. Start the Intellij again.

Comment: This is a really helpful and the quick solution worked for me as well.

Comment: Worked for me too, using Android Studio 4.1.1
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283, built on November 4, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Comment: Feb 2021 - This also worked for me. If it helps anyone I'm working in Flutter with with AS Android Studio 4.0
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223, built on May 20, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Comment: This one work for me on IntelliJ as well, Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget to save your current .idea folder first, since deleting it and regenerating it will remove all of you local configuration such as custom linting scoops, run configuration, code style etc.
Then add the missing files and/or replace the newly regenerated workspace.xml.

Answer (score 6):

I have solved this issue in android studio by following steps -

```
 1. Close Android Studio 
 2. Go to my app codebase directory
 3. Delete the .idea folder
 4. Start the Android studio again.
```

It's working like wow.

Answer (score 0):

i figured out that i was not having settings.gradle in my github
content

```
include ':app'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it didn't work to download my repository again, I had to update Android Studio from 3.3 to 3.4.

I don't know if it's an isolated case or if someone else can solve this problem in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

In **.idea** folder delete **modules.xml** and restart Android Studio.

This will resolve the error by regenerating and linking the files again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle > check generate *.iml files for modules imported from gradle.
After change settings, resync project, iml files will be generated.

[image]