# Android Studio remove package from different modules

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How to remove a complete package from different modules.
None of these solutions are working:

```
dependencies {
    compile (project(':..:libraries:utilities')) {
        exclude group: 'com.test.utils'
    }
}
```

Or

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.test.utils', module: 'utilities'
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710290/how-to-delete-a-module-in-android-studio

Comment: I don't want to delete my module at all, I just when to remove some packages from different module at compile time using gradle.