# How can I correctly delete a project into Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide

I am absolutly new in Android development and in **Android Studio** (I am mainly a Java EE developer).

So I have the following problem: I have created a new project into Android Studio and I have to delete it. In Eclipse I simply select my projecct and, right click on it and delete it. But I can't find this operation in Android Studio (after have selected the project into the **project** drop down tab.

It also seems to me that I can't close a project (as I do in Eclipse).

Why? What am I missing? How can I delete my project into Android Studio?

Comment: Close the project, and delete the project folder from your computer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File > Close Project

move your mouse cursor on the project and press Delete keyboard button.

This may be the [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710290/how-to-delete-a-module-in-android-studio).

Try this too. 
[image: this could help]

Answer (score 0):

In 'File' menu you will get 'Close project' option. After closing project simply delete the project from your hard drive.