# Delete a project completely from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to delete a project from `Android Studio 2.2.2`. I tried these steps:

1. [Delete module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24592192/1043882)
2. Delete from recent files
3. [Delete directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16710493/1043882)
4. Delete by nautilus

But directory `AndroidStudioProjects/Application_Name/.idea/` returns back with these contents after restarting Android Studio:

```
./misc.xml
./compiler.xml
./workspace.xml
./copyright/profiles_settings.xml
```

How delete a module completely?

Comment: i guess these files pertain to the entire project instead of a specific module

Comment: @nandsito I do not think like you. Pay attention to path of `/.idea/` directory which is a sub directory of `AndroidStudioProjects/Application_Name/`

Comment: a module is located inside the project directory, e.g. `AndroidStudioProjects/Application_Name/module_name`. This `.idea` directory is directly below the main project dir

Comment: @nandsito OK, you are right. I edited question ... .

Comment: you can delete `Application_Name` directory and everything goes away. Is that what you really want?

Comment: incinerate your hard drive?

Comment: why you aren't deleting it from folder path?

Comment: @nandsito Thank you for your reply, I confused by terms "project" and "module". I thought "module" is "project" and that was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm beginner in "Android Studio" and confused terms "project" and "module". So when I wanted to delete a project, did deleting a module and that was the real problem.

Finally I did these steps:

1. Closed the project
2. Removed that from "recent projects list"
3. Deleted project directory by "System File manager"

More details are described [here](http://tekeye.uk/android/delete-project-android-studio).