# How to delete Library/Module in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am working on a project on Android Studio where I am using some libraries. But out of them one library/module is not of any use. Now I want to remove/delete that particular Module. But when I right clicked on that module no delete option shows. I then went to Android Project folder in my C Drive and deleted that module's folder. But still that empty module is showing in android studio. How to remove it totally??

Comment: Remove it from build.gradle.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Go to File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies -> Select library/module -> click minus(-) -> Confirm selection from alert.

**Alternative**

If the above solution does not work then try this:

firstly remove the library from your build.gradle file and then delete it from the project structure.

Answer (score 19):

Go to File > Project Structure > Select the module in modules and press minus(-) on the top left. This will remove the library but you will have to manually remove the files form your project . [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710290/how-to-delete-a-module-in-android-studio)  link will help you in better understanding.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes the modules won't be showing in the module settings dialog. You have to check the **.idea folder** and **modules.xml** file and manually remove the **unwanted** modules (take caution though).

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: had a problem where by i deleted the module manually not knowing there were particular steps to follow. Only your answer led me to deleting it properly and not have it show in the ide

Comment: Yes it indeed helped me :). But in my project it was modules.xml not .iml, any idea why? @Monster Brain

Answer (score 2):

open `build.gradle` file, remove line which you dont want in your dependencies.
clean and rebuild your project..

if you applying module, open `setting.gradle`, remove module from there

Answer (score 2):

Delete the path in build,grade(app) then
Go to File > Project Structure > Select the module in modules and press minus(-) on the top left. This will remove the library but you will have to manually remove the files form your project .

Answer (score 0):

Just need to remove it from build.gradle(app)

```
   implementation(project(":core:yourLibraryModuleName"))
```

and then remove it from 'setting.gradle'

```
   include ':core:yourLibraryModuleName'
```

and finally, go to the project item to show your project files and delete your module and sync your project

Answer (score 0):

just right-click on the module/library, click on **Open In**, and delete the folder.

Answer (score -1):

Remove liebrary name from include in setting.Gradle from gradle Scripts